# viewForHeaderInSection - What to return for no header?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UIViewController` with several `UITableView`s imbedded in it.  For some of the tables, I need to show a custom header view with multiple labels.  For other tables, I don't want to show a header at all (that is, I want the first cell in `myTable2` to be right at the top of the frame for `myTable2`).  Here's roughly what I have:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.myTable1)
    // Wants Custom Header
    {        
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,tableView.contentSize.width,20);

        // ... Do stuff to customize view ...

        return view;
    }
    elseIf (tableView == self.myTable2)
    // Wants No header
    {
        return nil;
        // also tried
        // return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)];
        // but that didn't work either
    }
}
```

This works great for the custom headers, but for the tables where I don't want any header, it's showing a white box.  I figured that `return nil;` would prevent any header from being shown for that table.  Is that assumption correct?  Is there something else overwritting that?  How can I make it so nothing shows?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Whenever you implement the `viewForHeaderInSection` method you must also implement the `heightForHeaderInSection` method. Be sure to return `0` for the height for sections that have no header.

Comment: Yep, just what I needed.  Thanks.  If only XCode were smart enough to tell me I have to implement them together - one can dream I suppose.

Comment: If you read the docs for `viewForHeaderInSection` you will see: "This method only works correctly when `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` is also implemented."

Comment: Well would you look at that.  All the more reason why XCode should catch it I guess.

Answer (score 5):

If you use this way you don't need to calculate the height.

```
tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 50
```

If you have empty sections you can set the height to zero or you don't need this method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if section == 2 {
            return 0
        }
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

check this code ,as per @rmaddy comments

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

if (tableView == self.myTable1)
    // Wants Custom Header

{
    //custome header height
    return 20.0f;//height of custom header

    }
    elseIf (tableView == self.myTable2)
                    // Wants No header
    {
        return 0;
    }


}
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (tableView == self.myTable1)
    // Wants Custom Header
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,tableView.contentSize.width,20);

                    // ... Do stuff to customize view ...

                    return view;
                    }
                    elseIf (tableView == self.myTable2)
                    // Wants No header
                    {
                        return nil;
                    }
}
```